# Why did his sister make a scary face?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, after-earth

I am taking about [After Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1815862/).

In the scene the boy was sleeping on his hand-made raft and his dream was being shown. After hearing the conversation I think that the boy wanted to talk to his sister more but his sister wants to wake him up and she succeeds so after making a wounded face.

Why did she make such a face? Was it all about fear?

Comment: From what I recall, she was trying to wake him up because he was in danger (in the real world) and got him to snap out of it by making the face which reminding him that she had died.

Answer (score 3):

As requested, my comment has become an answer

From what I recall, she was trying to wake him up because he was in danger (in the real world) and got him to snap out of it by making the face which reminded him that she had died which startled him awake.